# Cannot find property of undefined

Tags: angular

I am getting error   Cannot read property 'data' of undefined in my angular 8 application when making a service call. If i put the if condition in the component code in my component 
  I dont get error but if i put th if condition in the html logic i still get the error. What is the issue ?

UI

```
<div *ngIf="!hideEverything && !endOfAgreements && myData" class="agreementContainer">
  <ul class="agreementSectionList">
    <li *ngFor="let agreement of myData; let i=index;"
        class="agreementSection"
        [ngClass]="{
          'disabled': (i > activeBtn),
          'current': (i === activeBtn),
          'accepted': (i <= previousSection)
        }">
      <a> {{ agreement.code }}
        <ng-container *ngIf="i <= previousSection">
          <fa-icon [icon]="['fas', 'check-circle']" style="float: right;"></fa-icon>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container *ngIf="i > previousSection">
          <fa-icon [icon]="['fas', 'window-close']" style="float: right;"></fa-icon>
        </ng-container>
      </a> <!-- (click)="termClicked(i)" -->
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Component

```
   ngOnInit() {
    this.getOutstandingAgreements(this.currentUser);
  }


  public getOutstandingAgreements(Id: number) {
    console.log(Id);
    this.agreementsService.getOutstandingAgreements(Id).subscribe((data: AgreementsModel[]) => {
         this.myData = data;
          // if (this.myData) {
         this.agreementData = this.myData[0].data;
         this.agreementLength = this.myData.length;

         this.calculateRemainingDaysLeft(0);
        } 
        );
    }
```

Comment: It means `this.myData[0]` is undefined. If this is possible then you should check whether this exists before trying to access it.

Comment: Data is taking a time to load and html render first so on that time you did't have the value so in `ngIf` it throws error

Comment: @YashRami The only code that is accessing a property called `data` is in the component. That's where the error is.

Comment: try to add if condition before accessing the data like this `if(this.myData != null)` which check if data is null or not and undefined or not at the same time. let me know if it is working or not.

Comment: the check in the component that i am currently doing which is commented works .My only question is i have seen in places where there is no check in the components subscribe

Comment: As i told you before in html if you are accessing the data before initializing that data you will get error of undefined so for preventing that error you can use `*ngIf="data != null"`.

Comment: I am not sure if you intended *ngIf="myData!= null" but i tried both data and myData but still get the same error

Answer (score 0):

In component declare myData variable like below

```
myData = [];
```

and in html check

```
<div *ngIf="!hideEverything && !endOfAgreements && myData.length > 0" class="agreementContainer">
```

Comment: The only code that is accessing a property called data is in the component. That's where the error is.

Comment: You are right kurt but wonder why there is necessity to do a check in the component as i dont see anywhere in the examples